# Inconsistent xib behaviour between iPhone 4 and iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, ios

I have created an app that contain two Xib file one for iPhone 4 And one for iPhone5. iphone 5 screen look ok but in iphone 4 it will different.

Here is the xib file for iPhone 4

[image]

And here is the simulator screen.

[image]

My xib file size is 320*460. i dont have idea about this behavior. can any one plz help.

**UPDATE**

I am presenting my VC using this code

```
TransactionDetailViewController * transactionDetailViewController;

    //select the zib according to the screen size
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    if (screenBounds.size.height == 568) {
        transactionDetailViewController = [[TransactionDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TransactionDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        transactionDetailViewController = [[TransactionDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TransactionDetailViewController_iPhone4" bundle:nil];
    }

    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:transactionDetailViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise about what is wrong?

Comment: @trojanfoe: I think the issue is in his simulator he is missing those two red buttons places on the xib. (It is hidden due to tabbar)

Comment: @trojanfoe as you can see in xib file my content fit properly but in simulater it goes out of bount i have tried to specify `Autoresizing` option in scale panel put it does not help me.

Comment: @MidhunMP you are right...

Comment: which xcode u are using turn off auto layout

Comment: and in xib select top bar as navigation bar

Comment: @amar done both thing but result is same

Comment: check the height of your view it must be more 544 after navigation bar

Comment: @amar nop its same as i said....

Comment: Ok got it you are loading the iPhone5 nib both the times

Comment: @amar no i have checked that also both tome different xib is called, i think this issue is raised bcoz my current ViewController is third child in my navigation controller hierarchy. i have tried your suggestion differently first i have added tabbar and navbar in xib and than i have resized my controller to fit in the size that have lest.

Answer (score 0):

You are loading iPhone 5 nib both the time. take a isIpad global flag set it depending upon the device then use this init method in your view controller

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    NSString  *nibName=nil;

    nibName=isiPad?@"viewController_iPhone5":@"viewController";// isIpad is flag set if device is iPhone5

    self = [super initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: amar see my update i am taking care of xib file when i am presenting it.

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone 4 screen is not resizing or scaling correctly and therefore some of the content is behind the tab bar.

The standard size for the tab bar is 49 high and the nav bar is 44 high. You could resize the view to be 320 x 367 as this is 460 - 49 - 44.

This is not the best solution admittedly but it may just work